# Show content based on a logic of decision - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a script where one can choose several options. At the end i want to implement a logic that depending on the choices chosen by the user content is displayed. So for example you start with three options:

If you select option 1 & option 3, Content A shows. However if you try selecting Option1 & option2 a set of different content is shown.

Here is a fiddle of what I have done so far, however it is not functioning correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/u4vuM/

Logic I am trying to implement to get his working:

```
for (var i in selections) {
    if (selections[i]) {
        content += '<li>' + i + '</li>';
    }

    if (selections[i] = 'TelevisionInternet'){
        var contentanswer = 'Testing this logic that works';
        $('#done').html(contentanswer);
    }
}
```

Comment: (selections[i] === 'TelevisionInternet')

Comment: @dougajmcdonald I did try that however logic is till not working

Comment: You never use your `content` var, do something like : `var contentanswer = 'Testing this logic that works<br />'+content+'</ul>';`

Comment: @NeeL Thanks for this, however irrelevant of which options I choose, the logic is still not working

Comment: @NeeL At the moment its working that choosing any option you choose once done button is pressed it shows the text 'Testing this logic that works'. I want it to work that only if option1 & Option2 is chosen that words comes up. If I choose option1 & Option 3 something else comes up

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/u4vuM/1/ and tell me if it suits your needs, if so i'll write an answer to explain better my solution

Comment: @NeeL it is somehow doing the logic I have in mind but not working to the full as when you press back content still stays there and it is not showing the correct selections

Comment: @NeeL your solution is working perfectttt.... what I need to do is make the match of the array unique, so what I mean is image this, I have three answer which will show up based on the below selections: Option1 & option 2 - Second set of selections: Option 3 & Option 4 - Third selection of answers Option 1, Option2, Option3 & Option 4. Now if I select the four options, all answers are being displayed, I only need one answer to display